Mismatch in Loss When Using `torch.load` and `resume_from_checkpoint`
I'm encountering an issue when trying to resume training using a saved checkpoint. When I use torch.load to load the model, I find that the initial loss is 4, whereas the loss saved in the checkpoint from the previous training is 2.3.
    if model_args.path_to_my_ckpt is not None:
        model.load_state_dict(
            torch.load(f"{model_args.path_to_my_ckpt}/pytorch_model.bin"), strict=True
        )
        logger.info(
            f"loading trained model from {model_args.path_to_my_ckpt}/pytorch_model.bin"
        )

I've also tried using Trainer(train_from_checkpoint=checkpoint_path), but the initial loss remains at 4.
here is the part of previous training log and the training states:
[INFO|trainer.py:2905] 2024-04-13 07:23:20,504 >> Saving model checkpoint to /home_path/checkpoints/test_use_mlm_chbz_dec
[INFO|configuration_utils.py:458] 2024-04-13 07:23:20,506 >> Configuration saved in /home_path/checkpoints/test_use_mlm_chbz_dec/config.json
[INFO|modeling_utils.py:1837] 2024-04-13 07:23:21,078 >> Model weights saved in /home_path/test_use_mlm_chbz_dec/pytorch_model.bin
[INFO|tokenization_utils_base.py:2181] 2024-04-13 07:23:21,081 >> tokenizer config file saved in /home_path/checkpoints/test_use_mlm_chbz_dec/tokenizer_config.json
[INFO|tokenization_utils_base.py:2188] 2024-04-13 07:23:21,083 >> Special tokens file saved in /home_path/checkpoints/test_use_mlm_chbz_dec/special_tokens_map.json

last lines in trainer_state.json
   {
      "epoch": 7.92,
      "learning_rate": 3.6662134375000002e-06,
      "loss": 2.2366,
      "step": 99850
    },
    {
      "epoch": 7.92,
      "learning_rate": 3.1453853125000002e-06,
      "loss": 2.2395,
      "step": 99900
    },
    {
      "epoch": 7.92,
      "learning_rate": 2.6245571875000002e-06,
      "loss": 2.2364,
      "step": 99950
    },
    {
      "epoch": 7.93,
      "learning_rate": 2.1037290625e-06,
      "loss": 2.2359,
      "step": 100000
    },
    {
      "epoch": 7.93,
      "step": 100000,
      "total_flos": 3.8100065615987343e+18,
      "train_loss": 2.39436900390625,
      "train_runtime": 66313.4695,
      "train_samples_per_second": 772.091,
      "train_steps_per_second": 1.508
    }
  ],
  "max_steps": 100000,
  "num_train_epochs": 8,
  "total_flos": 3.8100065615987343e+18,
  "trial_name": null,
  "trial_params": null
}

And here is the part of log when I use resume_from_checkpoint:
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ - ***** Running training *****
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Num examples = 6,458,670
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Num Epochs = 8
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Instantaneous batch size per device = 512
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 512
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Gradient Accumulation steps = 1
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Total optimization steps = 100,100
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Number of trainable parameters = 11,840,256
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Continuing training from checkpoint, will skip to saved global_step
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Continuing training from epoch 7
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Continuing training from global step 100000
04/16/2024 01:15:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Will skip the first 7 epochs then the first 11695 batches in the first epoch.

which turns out that it has load the ckpt successfully. The startup script (sh file) and data paths are identical to the previous training. Why is there a discrepancy in the loss values? Did I load the checkpoint incorrectly, or is there another issue?
transformers version: 4.29.0

Feel free to post your opinion, I am looking forward a solution or explanation about this issue.
